# Github Desktop Fatal: could not read username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm using GitHub Desktop, but it doesn't work anymore. I can't sync, fetch, push nor clone. I'm getting the following error as it opens a file explorer window:
[image]

I have tried running the mentioned ask-pass-trampoline.bat file with no avail.
I have also tried to sign out and log in again, and reinstall GitHub Desktop, but again with no avail.

I have read quite a lot online, but their problems are with their plugins, where they are able to fix it by changing some URLs, but I don't know how I would do that in the Desktop version.

It does work however in VisualStudio, but I can't clone new repositories from VisualStudio, so this needs to be fixed for the long term.